# Access multiple channels in OpenCV Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, mat

What is the Syntax to access ith row of channel::n of a multi channel matrix. I can access (i,j) element of channel::n but what is the syntax to use functions like row, rowRange, .....

Sample Code:

```
Mat M(10, 3, CV_32SC3);
cout << M.at<Vec3d>(0,0)[1] << endl;  // This works
cout << M.row(0)[1] << endl;    // Syntax of this
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are searching for the following:

```
 cv::Mat M(10, 3, CV_32SC3);
 cv::Mat_<cv::Vec3d> helpimg = M;
 helpimg .row(0).begin()[0][0] = 2.5;
```

I can compile it but i didn't test it. Tell if it works. You could use it also to get the cols values:

```
 helpimg .col(0).begin()[0][0] = 4.5;
```

Comment: note, that mat.col(0) does a deep copy, so `helpimg .col(0).begin()[0][0] = 4.5;` won't change helpimg's content !   (yes, ther's a difference between row() and col()!)

Answer (score 4):

```
Mat.row(0) returns a Mat, so it's the same game as before:

// if it's really INT 3channels(like your ex. above), you have to use m.at<Vec3i> !!
Mat M(10, 3, CV_32SC3);   

// 3rd row
Mat r = m.row(3);         

// r has only 1 row (3 elems), last pixel there
cout<< r.at<Vec3i>(0,2)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about doing this:

```
 cout << M.row(0).col(1) << endl;
```

The `Mat::row` function returns a `Mat`, so you can call either `row` or `col` on the result again to get the row or column you need from it.